# How to run a program when specific hard drive is connected (in Debian)?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, truecrypt

I want to automatically run a specific command whenever a drive (a specific drive, or any drive) is hot-plugged. I am running a headless Debian system.

To be more specific, I want to auto-mount the drive. I could do this with AutoFS, but this is a Truecrypt drive, and AutoFS won't work with that AFAIK. So I need to execute some kind of script whenever a drive is connected, which will detect the drive and run the necessary commands.

How can I do something automatically in response to a drive being connected? Then again, how can I do something else in response to the drive being removed?

Comment: I think you are looking for udev.

Comment: Yes, with udev is it possible, although it needs a deep dig in its soul.

Comment: You should take a look at this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103908/how-to-trigger-a-script-with-udev-when-connecting-sda-but-not-sda1-x which does something very similar to what you wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually quite easy: you need to write a custom udev rule, which you can place in

```
  /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules
```

The advantage of doing so is that your custom rule will be read before the other rules.

This file will contain a single line of this form

```
  <conditions to be met> KERNEL=="sd?1", NAME="my_usb_adapter", RUN+="/home/my_name/bin/my_program"
```

The meaning of this is:

1. 'conditions to be met' are a number of conditions, specific to your disk, which identify it uniquely, so that no action is performed when a different HDD is inserted;
2. KERNEL=="sd?1" tells udev to start checking this rule only when new partitions /dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1,... are detected. If you need, you can do the same not with a partition, but with the device, in which case KERNEL=="sd?" is the appropriate statement.
3. NAME="my_usb_adapter" will create a persistent node at /dev/my_usb_adapter, so that you know where to find the dev to be mounted, if you need to mount it.
4. The RUN rule is self-evident. Remember to make `my_program` executable without requiring terminal input or output.

You can obtain the information necessary to perform the matching with the command:

```
 udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb)
```

if your disk is /dev/sdb, otherwise modify as you see fit. This will provide a large amount of info. I would search for

```
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="18a5"
  ATTRS{idProduct}=="0302"
  ATTRS{serial}=="TT0E4E008XW3DT9H"
```

(these values are for one of my USB dongles, your values will be different). One important caveat: the matching rules must be taken from the same parent device, you cannot mix them.

Now we can write the final rule as:

```
 ATTRS{idVendor}=="18a5", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0302", ATTRS{serial}=="TT0E4E008XW3DT9H", KERNEL=="sd?1", NAME="my_usb_adapter", RUN+="/home/my_name/bin/my_program"
```

Keep in mind that udev files cannot break lines: if you do, udev will see the broken line as two separate rules. There will be no output to your terminal. Also, I have been quite careful in distinguishing `=`, `==`, and `+=`: make sure you introduce no mistakes in this.